# Applescript: Making a self-quitting script

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript which launches an application on computer startup.
The problem is that the script stays open in the background and prevents the machine from restarting, unless I force-quit the said script (The script is saved as an application).

How do I make the script quit itself after performed the actions?

Here is what I have (On OSX 10.8):

```
on run
do shell script "#!/bin/sh
# luxconsole control

/Applications/LuxRender/LuxRender.app/Contents/MacOS/luxconsole &"
quit
end run
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
on run
do shell script "/Applications/...  > /dev/null 2>&1 &" 
quit
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

```
do shell script "killall -yourapp-"
```

put that at the end of your script

Comment: If the first shell script never returns, it will never reach your proposed line. Mark's answer will allow the shell script to return immediately.